# How to avoid "about:blank" while doing form action with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, javascript-objects

I am trying to use multiple submit forms in javascript but it opens `about:blank` along with the requested form actions URLs in next tab

my code:

```
<form class="search_content" action="/" method="post" target='_blank' id="form1" name="form1">
 
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required>
     
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" >
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" >

   
  
</form>

<button  onclick="submitForms()">
        Go Search !
      </button>
```

my javascript code

as you see I use the check box to enable the different action URLs... when I run my code, it will open three new tabs and one "about:blank" tab. which should not open in my code

can anyone help me with how to do this kind of multiple action method with javascript and checkbox

```
<script>
function submitForms() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");

  
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("form1").action =
            "https://www.example.com/action_page.php";
            document.getElementById("form1").target='_blank';
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    
  }   
  if (checkBox1.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("form1").action =
            "https://www.example1.com/action_page.php";
            document.getElementById("form1").target='_blank';
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  } 
  
  if (checkBox2.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("form1").action =
            "https://www.example2.com/action_page.php";
            document.getElementById("form1").target='_blank';
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  }else{

            
            
  }
  
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `preventDefault()`?

Comment: hi @CristianTraìna i am new to javascript... so i followed mostly from  StackOverflow only.. and i am not familiar with preventDefault... and I am not sure how to use this method "preventDefault" inside my code.. could you guide me

Comment: Well, you shouldn't start from StackOverflow, you should start from tutorials, books, and so on. StackOverflow should be your last resort :)

Comment: Understood, thanks @CristianTraìna as you said, i will start from tutorials... thank you..

Comment: @CristianTraìna yes it seems the answers seem to work for my code as well, I will do some basic learning and improve myself as you said...